Django + React Axios Network Error: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials expected 'true'
I am working on a web app running React on the front end and Django on the back end and am running into a issue when sending api requests to the back end. When attempting a POST or GET request, there occurs a Axios Network Error popping up on the site reading:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/is_authenticated/. (Reason: expected ‘true’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Credentials’).

Nevertheless, when inspecting the network request in Firefox, the JSON response does contain the correct data and has a 200 OK status. Just a warning appears "Response body is not available to scripts (Reason: CORS Missing Allow Credentials)".
My current backend settings using CorsMiddleware are
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'app',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    ...
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS: True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False, 
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://localhost:8000',
]

When sending the request I have the current axios post call.
axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/login/`, request, { withCredentials: true })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      if (data.warning) return;
        localStorage.setItem("currentUser", data.user);
    });

Is there a setting I am overlooking or specific error in my code? Or are there certain front-end settings on Axios that I need to update to allow credentials? Thank you for your help.

Could you try to the line corsheaders up above app.
in this order,
corsheaders,
app

tried and still returning the same errors :(, am now attempting with fetch requests instead of axios

tried but whenever I did 'credentials: include', same problem occurs

oops, this is embarrassing but after head banging for about 4 hours. Realized I did Cors-Allow-Credentials: True instead of Cors-Allow-Credentials = True.
